# Deleting a appointment from a db

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

I'm trying to delete an made appointment that has a specific "CNP" inserted by the user when the appointment has been made, when I search for it, it shows, but when I  try to delete it, nothing happens, I'll paste the full code of the controller so you can understand better.

```
public class ProgramariDBController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField cpn;
    @FXML
    private TableView<DetaliiProgramari> ProgrDB;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DetaliiProgramari, String> Nume;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DetaliiProgramari, String> Prenume;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DetaliiProgramari, String> Data;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DetaliiProgramari, String> Ora;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DetaliiProgramari, String> Departament;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DetaliiProgramari, String> Doctor;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DetaliiProgramari, String> Nr_telefon;

    public LogareController Numeutilzator = new LogareController();
    private ObservableList<DetaliiProgramari> Info;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle ResurcesFORDAYS) {
        // TODO

    }

    @FXML
    private void AfiseazaProgramari(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
          ConectaredB ConectaredB=new ConectaredB();
            Connection conectare=ConectaredB.logareDB();

            Info = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            String CNP=cpn.getText();
            ResultSet IncDate = conectare.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM programari where CNP=" + CNP);
            while (IncDate.next()) {

                Info.add(new DetaliiProgramari(IncDate.getString(2), IncDate.getString(3), IncDate.getString(4),
                        IncDate.getString(5), IncDate.getString(6), IncDate.getString(7), IncDate.getString(8)));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error"+ex);
        }


        Nume.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Nume"));
        Prenume.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Prenume"));
        Data.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Data"));
        Ora.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Ora"));
        Departament.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Departament"));
        Doctor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Doctor"));
        Nr_telefon.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Nr_telefon"));

        ProgrDB.setItems(null);
        ProgrDB.setItems(Info);
    }

    @FXML // Here is the method that I've wrote.
    private void delete(ActionEvent event) throws IOException  {
        try { 


            String sql = "delete FROM programari where CNP=?";
            ConectaredB ConectaredB=new ConectaredB();
            Connection conexiune=ConectaredB.logareDB();
            PreparedStatement ps = conexiune.prepareStatement(sql);
            String CNP=cpn.getText();
            ps.setString(1, CNP);
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Will do, thank you.

Comment: better start _now_ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL delete doesn't return a `ResultSet`, you need to call [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--). Change this

```
ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
```

to

```
ps.executeUpdate();
```

And if you want to verify the result, you can tell how many *rows* were removed with the result.

```
int count = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thank alot you btw! I'll accept the respons as soon as it will let me to.